# CPU and memory usage of scikit-learn estimators

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn, cpu, cpu-usage

Is there a way to monitor or save the memory & CPU usage for scikit-learn estimators, who are running in the code?

For example:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor 

clf = RandomForestRegressor().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

To get smth like:

```
Memory used: 1 MB

CPU % used: 5%
clocks per instruction (CPI) = 20
```

I tried with `memory-profiler`, but so far it doesnt work with many estimators.